# why i am not able to run my flutter project in android constantly getting gradle error?

Tags: android, flutter, build.gradle

[image: image to provide more information about my problem]        [![* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not create task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8'.
> Failed to find Platform SDK with path: platforms;android-31

```
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1][1]][1]
```

i'm getting error constantly regarding gradle task have wasted 3 days by searching for it but didn't got any solution yet
information might be needed

android/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2'//by default it was 4.1.2 but was getting error Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01 so I changed to 7.0.2 considering someone's suggestion
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
```

gradle-wraper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-all.zip //before it was gradle-6.7
```

Comment: Can you post your Flutter Doctor output?  You might have some license issues and that will tell you if that is the case.

Comment: Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.556], locale en-IN)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[√] VS Code (version 1.65.0)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
this is the output

Answer (score 0):

Failed to find Platform SDK with path: platforms;android-31 that means there is no android SDK folder

1. to get the latest Android API on you computer, run android list target, if you don't find Android API 31 in the list, you might install it through Android studio

> $ android list target

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPKs8.jpg)

2. after installing Android API 31,

- find Android SDK Location in the project preferences
- check whether  sdk.dir is correct in "local.properties" file in android folder

Comment: thanks for your response but when i run android list target its coming that android is not recognised as internal or external command...

Comment: so it is required to set path environmental variables for android SDK. https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-set-android-sdk-path-in-windows-and-mac/